# Is it possible to resort an array mid for loop?

Tags: php, arrays

So the point of this function is to create balanced teams based on player rankings. My original code works just fine:

```
function playerCreate(){
global $teams, $players;
//find the average captain MMR
$averageTeams = averageteams();
sortTeams();
//Any captain above average add the lowest MMR player
for($i = 0; $i < count($teams);$i++){
  if ($teams[$i]['totalMMR'] > $averageTeams){
    addPlayer($i,0);
}
//Any captain below average MMR add the highest MMR player
else {
    addPlayer($i,count($players)-1);
}
}}
```

However, the problem with the balance is half way through the four loop it starts adding the highest rated players to the 4th lowest rated teams. This is because the for loop goes in a specific order and will add team 6's player before team 10's which by my sorting function will be the lowest rated team.

Is there a way to sort mid for loop or another way to do this to better balance these teams?

I created a function called rSortTeams() that will sort the teams from highest rated to lowest rated instead, but when I try and call it mid for loop it all messes up.

sortTeams function:

```
function sortTeams(){
   global $teams;
   usort($teams, function($a, $b) {
       return $a['totalMMR'] - $b['totalMMR'];
   });
}
function rSortTeams(){
   global $teams;
   usort($teams, function($a, $b) {
     return $b['totalMMR'] - $a['totalMMR'];
   });
}
```

Here is the three arrays:

```
$captains = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++){
  $players[] = array('name' => 'Player ' . $i, 'MMR' => rand(2800,4200));
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
  $captains[] = array('name' => 'Captain ' . $i, 'MMR' => rand(3200,4200));
}
$teams = array();
//put captains on teams
for($i = 0;$i < count($captains); $i++){
$teams[] = array('name' => 'Team ' . ($i + 1), 'captain' => $captains[$i], 'players' => array(), 'totalMMR' => $captains[$i]['MMR']);
}
```

And the addPlayer function:

```
function addPlayer($team,$newPlayer){
  global $teams, $players;
  $teams[$team]['players'][] = $players[$newPlayer];
  $teams[$team]['totalMMR'] += $players[$newPlayer]['MMR'];
  unset($players[$newPlayer]);
  $players = array_values($players);
}
```

Comment: can you post sample array values for $averageTeams, $teams, $players? it will surely help.

Comment: Done $averageTeams is just a variable calling one of my functions. It was acting weird when I tried to call the function directly into the comparison.

Comment: what about the addPlayer()?.

Comment: Added that too now, but I think I figured it out eventually. Maybe not the most efficient way to do it. But it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I changed the function to this:

```
function playerCreate(){
  global $teams, $players;
  //find the average captain MMR
  $averageTeams = averageteams();
  $belowAverage = 0;
  $aboveAverage = 0;
  sortTeams();
  for($i = 0; $i < count($teams);$i++){
    if ($teams[$i]['totalMMR'] > $averageTeams){
      $aboveAverage++;
    }
    else {
      $belowAverage++;
    }
  }
  for($y = 0; $y < $belowAverage; $y++){
    addPlayer($y,count($players)-1);
  }
  for($z = count($teams)-1;$z > count($teams) - 1 - $aboveAverage; $z--){
    addPlayer($z,0);    
  }
 }
```

Comment: well kudos to you for figuring that out.